# How update all registers based in select in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi i have the ite table with 13.000 registers:

for example my "ite" table:

```
|fid      |     pc_cadastral |     fid_parceles
|--------------------------------
| 1       |      5435        |     
| 2       |      6789        |     
| 3       |      3456        |     
| 4       |      7896        |   
| 5       |      3322        |  
...
...
```

I create the column called "fid_parceles" in "ite" table and is a fk from "parceles" table.

for example my "parceles" table:

```
fid     |   pc_cadastral       
----------------------------
1       |      7896           
2       |      3322            
3       |      5435         
4       |      6789   
5       |      3456      
..
...
```

So how can i update the fid_parceles based in pc_cadastral between the two tables in a unique setence for no repeat 13.000 times the same?

for example the result in "ite" table will be

```
fid      |     pc_cadastral |     fid_parceles
--------------------------------
 1       |      5435        |        3
 2       |      6789        |        4 
 3       |      3456        |        5
 4       |      7896        |        1
 5       |      3322        |        2 
......
```

Comment: Why bother? You already have a foreign key relationship between `ite.pc_cadastral` and `parceles.pc_cadastral`

Comment: yep but i have added the column after the insert all the dates. So all are empty bro @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE ite
JOIN parceles USING (pc_cadastral)
SET ite.fid_parceles = parceles.fid;
```

`parceles.pc_cadastral` must be unique. If not then indefinite `parceles.fid` value from all possible ones will be used for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
update ite
join parceles on ite.pc_cadastral = parceles.pc_cadastral
set ite.fid_parceles = parceles.fid;
```

It will update `ite` table based on `join` condition with `parceles` table.

[Demo with sample data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7kcmoGf8SJuPfBcRdAARpW/0)